# jQuery Autocomplete with Coldfusion remote data source

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, coldfusion, jquery-autocomplete

Every tutorial and example I researched was just enough "off" of what I need to make it very frustrating.  I have a Coldfusion page that uses Twitter Bootstrap and jQuery.  I need an autocomplete function to list schools.  This should be pretty easy.  I get no response at all.  And there are no errors (that I can find using dev tools).

This may be somewhat of a kludge after so many attempts. IE; I don't know the difference between `source: '/assets/cf/fetchColleges.cfm'` and the ajax call. I think source is a local/client data source.

HTML:

```html
<div class="row">   
<div class="span9">
<input size="34" type="text" name="CollegeName" id="CollegeName" value="" />
  <div id="results"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```js
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {  

    $("#CollegeName").autocomplete({
        source: '/assets/cf/fetchColleges.cfm',
        minLength: 3,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $('#company_id').val(ui.item.id);
            // go get the company data
            $.ajax({
                type: 'Get',
                url: '/services/GradTax.cfc?method=GetSchoolsJson&returnformat=json',
                data: {searchPhrase: query.term},
                dataType: 'json',
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // show error
                alert(errorThrown)},
                success: function(result) {
                response(result);
                }
            });
        }
    }); 
});
```

CFC:

```coldfusion
<cffunction name="GetSchoolsJson" access="remote" >
<cfargument name="QueryString" required="true" />
<cfquery name="QComp" datasource="#request.dsn_live#">
select name
from companies
WHERE School_Flag = 'True' AND [Name] LIKE '%#Request.QueryString#%' AND (Status_Flag IS NULL OR Status_Flag = 'A') AND Grad_Tax_Flag = 'True'
ORDER BY [NAME] ;
</cfquery>

<cfset var comp = structNew() />
<cfoutput query="QComp">
<cfset comp["name"] = '#qcomp.name#' />
</cfoutput>
<cfreturn comp>
</cffunction>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `source` option definitely need not be static. In fact, I think that's mainly what is wrong with your declaration of the widget and specification of the options. It looks like you are using `GradTax.cfc` as your dynamic source. So you need to set your `source` option to be a function which calls your dynamic source via AJAX.  On AJAX success inside the `source` option, you call the `response` callback provided in the declaration `source: function(request, response)`.  That function signature is specified by jQuery as what is required if you are going to have a function providing dynamic results. In that case, `request` contains information about the current input in the autocomplete box that you can use (you use `request.term` to pass through *what* to autocomplete, and `response` represents the callback function that will get called once your AJAX function completes. See more in the [jQuery UI documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source).

You can search for the `source` option to see pretty much the same info I provided above. What you need to do (or close to it at least) is (not tested by the way):

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {  

    $("#CollegeName").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'Get',
                url: '/services/GradTax.cfc?method=GetSchoolsJson&returnformat=json',
                data: {searchPhrase: request.term},
                dataType: 'json',
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    // show error
                    alert(errorThrown)
                },
                success: function(result) {
                    response(result); //Need to make sure result is an array of objects at
                                      // least containing the necessary properties used by
                                      // jQuery autocompleter. Each object should, I believe,
                                      // contain a 'label' and a 'value' property. See docs for an example:
                                      // http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 3,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $('#company_id').val(ui.item.id);
            //this should take care of what needs to happen when you actually click / select one of the items that was autocompleted. See documentation above and search for the 'select' option for usage.
        }
    });
});
```

Referring to the [jQuery remote jsonp data source Demo](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp), note that in the AJAX success callback above, the response from the AJAX call does not *need* to be an array of objects containing a `value` and a `label` property, but the object that gets passed in to the `response` callback does need to have those. That's exactly how the jQuery demo works. They manually `$.map` the response to be an array of objects containing `value` and `label` based on their ajax response. `label` is what is actually displayed in the interface of the autocompleter, i.e. what the user would see, whereas `value` is what is set to the original input's value. Note in their example above that `value` is also used in the `select` option. Not the most straightforward thing in the world but when you see what is going on it's not too bad to work with!

Here it is working in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sbCwb/1/). That will get a 404 since the autocomplete endpoint won't be found, but you'll see if you watch developer tools that the text to be autocompleted is passed along in the query string (you'll get alerted saying there was an error), it's a basic proof-of-concept.

Comment: Yes, I pretty much figured out the "source" question.  However, using your code and my original, there is no evidence that anything at all is happening when I type in the CollegeName element.  I have breakpoints set and nothing shows under "network" tab in dev tools.

Comment: Interesting. Check out this jsfiddle, it's definitely working. I start typing and after 3 characters I get a 404 on GradTax.cfc, obviously since I don't have it. http://jsfiddle.net/sbCwb/1/

Comment: Here's what I see, for example: GET http://fiddle.jshell.net/services/GradTax.cfc?method=GetSchoolsJson&returnformat=json&searchPhrase=test 404 (NOT FOUND). The Error also gets alerted to me. Is that not doing the same thing for you? In that case, I'll back up and say to make sure you are referencing both the jQuery library as well as jQuery UI https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide

Comment: One problem was the path to the jquery-ui.js file.  So I pointed to google and got a response.  It was an error; The QUERYSTRING parameter to the GetSchoolsJson function is required but was not passed in.

Comment: I changed data to: data: {QueryString: request.term},

It works now but not getting good results.  I'm sure it's on me.